# Showing all Frobenius forms are given by multiplication with an invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $\mathbb{k}$. A Frobenius form is a linear functional $\varepsilon : A \rightarrow \mathbb{k}$ that contains no nontrivial left ideals in its nullspace.

My question has two parts. The first part is about showing that, given a Frobenius form $\varepsilon$, the map $\varepsilon' : A \rightarrow \mathbb{k}$ given by $x \mapsto \varepsilon(u x)$, where $u \in A$ is invertible, is also a Frobenius form. I think I have done it by using a result that there being no nontrivial left ideals in the nullspace of $\varepsilon$ is equivalent to there being no nontrivial right ideals in the nullspace of $\varepsilon$, but the book I'm reading plainly states that the ideals in the nullspaces must be the same as $u$ is invertible, so I was wondering if I'm overlooking something obvious.

The second part is about showing that, in fact, every Frobenius form on $A$ is given in this way. One result states that if $\varepsilon$ is a Frobenius form, then there is a left $A$-linear isomorphism $A \xrightarrow{\sim} A^*$ given by $1 \mapsto \varepsilon$. The book I'm reading gives an argument considering two such isomorphisms (the second being given by $1 \mapsto \varepsilon'$) by which I'm very confused, so perhaps someone can explain it better.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** okay, so I think I figured out the first bit as follows. Let $I$ be a left ideal in $A$. Then $\varepsilon(I) = 0 \Rightarrow \varepsilon(u I) = 0 \Rightarrow \varepsilon'(I) = 0$ and also $\varepsilon'(I) = 0 \Rightarrow \varepsilon'(u^{-1} I) = 0 \Rightarrow \varepsilon(u (u^{-1} I)) = \varepsilon((u u^{-1}) I) = \varepsilon(I) = 0$, so the left ideals in the nullspaces must be the same. (I did overthink it previously for some reason.)

However, the second part of the question still stands for me.